# A2DP sound server on Ubuntu server 20.04 (raspberry pi)

Tags: server, sound, bluetooth, a2dp

I have a Pi runnig Ubuntu server (aarch64) and plugged in my old 2.1 speaker system. In the end I want to be able to stream music from my phone to the speakers over blueutooth and the Pi. I tried dozens of the (outdated) tutorials in the www, but I gave up. I dont care about ALSA or PA. It should be easy to setup and work out of the box. Preferrably even dockerized, such that I can just `docker-compose up a2dp`, since I dont want to go through the hassle each time I update my system. However I know it's cumbersome due to the hardware interface so docker is not mandatory. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If what you are asking made any sense that would be a start. Is the old 2.1 speaker system Bluetooth? What have you tried we cant know so it does not help to say outdated tutorials.

Comment: Edited slightly. The outdated ones are bluez4. bluez5 has no Alsa support built in. BluezAlsa is not in the repos yet (well raspbian has it) building it is a pain (tried in a docker container)